# UTF-8 encode error when configuring Sentry Addon to Heroku app

Tags: django, heroku, sentry

I am trying to configure Sentry addon on Heroku and I get an error

```
Encoding error. Please ensure that all data in the request can be interpreted as UTF-8.
```

I tried both command line and using the dashboard in the browser. I have checked my account settings and don't use any non - English characters.

Comment: Hey, this is a deploy gone bad and we're fixing it as we speak. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, much appreciated

Comment: Just catching up but we have deployed a fix 1-2 days ago, can you confirm?

Comment: Yep, all set up and good to go. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [Markus Unterwaditzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544347/markus-unterwaditzer) in the notes to the question, it seems it was an issue with Sentry. I can now confirm that it works.